# notation for connected sum $\#^n S^2 \times S^2$

Tags: general-topology, geometric-topology, spheres, 4-manifolds

What does the symbol $\#^n S^2 \times S^2$ mean in geometric topology?

I know the $\#$ symbol refers to a [connected sum](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_sum).   So that we delete a disk from each sphere and sew the two spheres according to a map $\phi : S^1 \to S^1$.  These could be classified by the corresponding element of the fundamental group $[\phi]=[n]\in \pi_1(S^1)$.

This guess is certainly wrong because the result should be a 4-manifold.

I don't even know which term to put into Google.

Answer (score 2):

It means the connected sum of $n$ copies of $S^2\times S^2$. That is, $\#^2 S^2\times S^2 = S^2\times S^2 \# S^2\times S^2$, $\#^3 S^2\times S^2 = S^2\times S^2\# S^2\times S^2\# S^2\times S^2$ and so on.

Answer (score 2):

It is the $n$-fold connected sum of $S^2\times S^2$, i.e. $$\#^n(S^2\times S^2):=\underbrace{(S^2\times S^2)\#(S^2\times S^2)\#\dots\#(S^2\times S^2)}_\text{$n$-many}.$$ In this particular case, this is just $n$ four-dimensional manifolds glued together along boundaries after removing $4$-balls from the respective manifolds (see [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_(mathematics)) for examples where we consider $\#^nS^1\times S^1$ for $n=1,2,3$). That is, $\#^nS^2\times S^2$ is a (orientable) 4-manifold with genus $n$.

Comment: Good, though note that $S^2 \times S^2$ is not a torus by any definition; it is a product of spheres, but a torus is specifically a product of some number of circles. It is 4-dimensional, not a surface (which is 2-dimensional). This manifold doesn't really have a better name than $S^2 \times S^2$.

Comment: Opss. @MikeMiller