# What does "#" mean here? "[these structures] are diffeomorphic to $\#^kS^1\times B^3$"

Tags: geometric-topology

I am reading *The topology of 4-manifolds* by Kirby.

At page 7 the author uses the symbol # what does it mean?

The sentence for context is this:

> However, the 3-handles and 4-handle of a closed $M^4$ together are diffeomorphic to $\#^kS^1\times B^3$...

Comment: I means connected sum.

Comment: [Connected sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_sum)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means [connected sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_sum), e.g. $S^1 \# S^1$. For details see, for example,

[connected sum of surfaces is well defined proof attempt](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1775986/connected-sum-of-surfaces-is-well-defined-proof-attempt)

For the "iterated" notation see here:

[notation for connected sum $\#^n S^2 \times S^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2896566/notation-for-connected-sum-n-s2-times-s2)

Comment: Not quite: In this particular case, Kirby means the "boundary connected sum" which is not the same as the ordinary connected sum.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I see, thank you. Still, for the OP it is good to know the symbol in general first. Further details depend of course on the context.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular passage, notation $\#$  is for the *boundary connected sum,* see my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3940800/boundary-of-a-connected-sum-is-it-connected/3941845#3941845) for the detailed definition and comparison to the usual connected sum.

Incidentally, one should be very proficient in basic algebraic topology to have any chance succeeding in reading Kirby's book.